# Proving there is no set of all ordered pair

Tags: solution-verification, set-theory

I proved it with Kuratowski's definition.

**Proof 1:** If there is a such set, say $\mathscr D$, we can form a set $\mathscr A = \{x\,|\, <x, y>\in\mathscr D\}$ by subset axiom. Then $\mathscr A$ is a set of all sets, which is the Russell's paradox.

**Proof 2:** If there is a such set, say $\mathscr D$, we can form a set $\mathscr A = \{x\,|\, x\in\bigcup\mathscr D\}$ by subset axiom. Then $\mathscr A$ is a set of all sets, which is the Russell's paradox.

I first wrote proof 1. But I noticed $\mathscr A$ is not a subset of $\mathscr D$. So I wrote proof 2. I think proof 2 is valid because $\mathscr A\subseteq\bigcup\mathscr D$, but as in proof 1 I wanted to bring the first element of every pair in $\mathscr D$ and resulting set is a set of all sets(I think this would be a smaller set than bring two elements in a pair and still too big to be a set). Can I successfully prove with this idea?

Comment: Proof 1 shows that the existence of a set of all ordered pairs implies the existence of a set of all sets. Then the way is free to find a contradiction (Russell). Why do you mind that $\mathscr A$ is not a subset of $\mathscr D$?

Comment: @drhab I'm learning set theory(in a basic level). So I'm trying to show every step clearly. If $\mathscr A$ is not a subset of $\mathscr D$ then we don't know whether $\mathscr A$ exists or not, I think. In proof 2 $\mathscr A$ exists but it differs from $\mathscr A$ in proof 1.

Comment: I see what you mean. If $\langle a,b\rangle=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}\in\mathscr D$ then $\{a\},\{a,b\}\in\bigcup\mathscr D$ so that $a,b\in\bigcup\bigcup \mathscr D$ so you can go for:$$\mathscr A=\{a\in\bigcup\bigcup\mathscr D\mid\langle a,b\rangle\in\mathscr D\}$$

Comment: ... If $\mathscr D$ is a set then also $\bigcup\bigcup\mathscr D$ is a set. Then the comprehension scheme states that $\mathscr A$ defined in my former comment is a set. However if $\mathscr D$ contains all ordered pairs then $\mathscr A$ contains all sets. Now you can go on with Russell in order to find a contradiction.

Comment: @drhab Thanks, you wrote what I imagined! And I realized in my proof 2 $x\in\bigcup\mathscr D$ should be $x\in\bigcup\bigcup\mathscr D$.

Comment: (1). Without Foundation (Regularity) it is easy to show by Extensionality that if the Kuratoski ordered pairs $\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ and $\{\{a'\},\{a',b'\}\}$ are equal then $a=a' $ and $ b=b'.$ I suspect we cannot do this  without Foundation with a different definition $(a,b)=\{a,\{a,b\}\}$ used by some authors. (2). We need the Pairing axiom to show there exists something other than $\emptyset.$

Comment: Also, you can use replacement instead of separation. Define a function $f$ such that $f(\langle x,y\rangle) = x$. If it's domain is $\mathcal{D}$, then its range is a set by replacement, which is the set of all sets.